# Set up environment variables for Gradle Runner and JUnit tests on Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

If you use Maven or JUnit it's easy to setup the environment variables used when you run your test classes.

[image]

But with Gradle there is not option available. I want to avoid to configure these environment variables where I use to program, because this is not handy once I work with several apps that sometimes have similar env variable names.

[image]

Is this a Gradle plugin problem? How are you solving this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your gradle build file you can easily specify which environment variables should be set when running the tests by configuring the `test` task with `test { environment 'VARIABLE', 'value' }` or similar. I do not have it 100% in mind right now.

Comment: Fastest answer ever I had here on StackOverflow. You should earn a medal @björn-kautler hehe

Comment: This works with a test task, I presume there is no good solution for getting this to work when right-clicking on a test class and selecting run?